# Folder not allowing permissions when in Docker (Linux)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

So I have a project I'm working on in Docker. I notice that in any given folder of the project, I am able to edit the permissions no problem. But for this specific theme folder, anytime I try to change permissions it throws this error:

`chmod: changing permissions of 'theme': Operation not permitted`

I'm not sure if this is a user/group related issue because I can edit every folder except that one.

I tried giving anyone access to that folder outside of Docker, but still can't edit it specifically in Docker.

Also, when I tried running chattr (while in Docker, I get this error:

`chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on theme`

Comment: Have you built your Docker image off of a local dockerfile? If so, what `USER` are you assigning within the Dockerfile?

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is your understanding of what "in Docker"/"outside of Docker" means. That understanding is probably limited, because you're omitting critical details in this question.

Comment: Please share your dockerfile and explain how it is that you chmod'ing it. There isn't enough details here to understand what is leading to your problem or even what you mean by "inside" vs "outside" of docker (assigning permissions before build and copying into docker via dockerfile/build VS executing into the running container and changing permissions?).